# Difference between two SQL queries and When to use each one

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actually I am confused regarding two SQL Queries. Both are giving me the same result but which one is preferred and when to use each one of them?

```
UPDATE Names  
SET Names.PhoneNumber = Phones.PhoneNumber 
FROM Names  INNER JOIN  Phones ON Names.id = Phones.id

UPDATE Names 
SET Names.PhoneNumber = Phones.PhoneNumber 
FROM Phones WHERE Names.ID = Phones.ID
```

Comment: are the same  ..  one use explicit join sintax and the second use(old)  implicit join sintax based  on where  ...  the first use the most recent join version

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That's product specific syntax.)

Comment: Depends on the DBMS product being used. e.g. the first one would be very inefficient (to the point of being wrong) in Postgres. In standard SQL, the UPDATE statement does not support a `FROM` clause or joins to begin with

Comment: As far as I know, only SQL Server would support both these queries, so I added that tag.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same.  In fact, they should generate the same execution plan.

Although there is no reason to choose one over the other, the `JOIN` form is typically used.  There is a simple reason:  SQL Server does not support aliases for the `UPDATE` table.  So, this does not work:

```
UPDATE Names n
    SET n.PhoneNumber = p.PhoneNumber 
    FROM Phones p 
    WHERE n.id = p.id;
```

However, this is fine:

```
UPDATE n  
    SET n.PhoneNumber = p.PhoneNumber 
    FROM Names n INNER JOIN
         Phones p
         ON n.id = p.id;
```

Also the use of the explicit `JOIN` makes it possible to use `LEFT JOIN`.

On the downside, the implicit `JOIN` version is compatible with more databases -- in particular, Postgres supports this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are observing the same result because they both meant the same meaning. The difference in the both queries is performance.
As we execute both query there is a performance difference and it is due to the execution plan that the planner is putting together.
WHERE clause -> he planner is choosing a route that is more efficient 
Join -> We can probably make the join work as fast (if not faster) by adding an index on the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any performance difference.you can use both ways.its totally depends on you.